# Record method calls in one session for replaying in future test sessions?

Tags: java

I have a backend system which we use a third-party Java API to access from our own applications. I can access the system as a normal user along with other users, but I do not have godly powers over it.

Hence to simplify testing I would like to run a real session and record the API calls, and persist them (preferably as editable code), so we can do dry test runs later with API calls just returning the corresponding response from the recording session - and this is the important part - without needing to talk to the above mentioned backend system.

So if my application contains line on the form:

```
 Object b = callBackend(a);
```

I would like the framework to first capture that `callBackend()` returned b given the argument a, and then when I do the dry run at any later time say "hey, given a this call should return b".  The values of a and b will be the same (if not, we will rerun the recording step).

I can override the class providing the API so all the method calls to capture will go through my code (i.e. byte code instrumentation to alter behavior of classes outside my control is not necessary).

What framework should I look into to do this?

---

EDIT:  Please note that bounty hunters should provide actual code demonstrating the behavior I look for.

Comment: if i understood you correctly this will be solution https://code.google.com/p/specs/

Comment: How complex are the datatypes that are passed to and returned from the backend?  If they are simple types then I think this problem is much simpler.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry how will you suggest I use the solution?

Comment: @EdPlese somewhat complex.  I believe they are fully serializable.

Comment: Why not using / extending real testing frameworks like EasyMock / Mockito (each with the PowerMock addon)? The only missing part would be to "persist" the learning phase.

Comment: @A.H. sure - got any suggestions on what might work best for me to look into?

Comment: Do the objects being passed (as parameters or return values) follow any sort of pattern, such as being a mix of Collections and JavaBeans?

Comment: @GargantuChet they can be serialized.  Would a restriction to collections and beans be beneficial?

Comment: It may. You'd mentioned wanting to persist as editable code, and a binary serialization can't be edited easily. If the values can be restricted to Collections, JavaBeans, and primitive types, then it may be possible to generate editable code blocks.

Comment: Sadly, having the framework you describe will not be particularly helpful unless the backend system is particularly simple.  Any function that is idempotent, independent of time, and completely dependent on inputs to derive outputs is some variant of database or mathematical function or untestable via the API.  The framework you describe, however, cannot model anything but that kind of function.

Comment: @OldPro: I agree, the requirements you are mentioning are quite essential. Although an answer has already been accepted, I will provide an answer to these requirements.

Answer (score 7):

Actually You can build such framework or template, by using proxy pattern. Here I explain, how you can do it using dynamic proxy pattern. The idea is to,

1. ***Write a proxy manager to get recorder and replayer proxies of API on demand***!
2. Write a wrapper class to store your collected information and also implement `hashCode` and `equals` method of that wrapper class for efficient lookup from `Map` like data structure.
3. And finally use recorder proxy to record and replayer proxy for replaying purpose.

*How recorder works:*

1. invokes the real API
2. collects the invocation information
3. persists data in expected persistence context

*How replayer works:*

1. Collect the method information (method name, parameters)
2. If collected information matches with previously recorded information then return the previously collected return value.
3. If returned value does not match, persist the collected information (As you wanted).

Now, lets look at the implementation. If your API is `MyApi` like bellow:

```
public interface MyApi {
    public String getMySpouse(String myName);
    public int getMyAge(String myName);
    ...
}
```

Now we will, record and replay the invocation of `public String getMySpouse(String myName)`. To do that we can use a class to store the invocation information like bellow:

```
    public class RecordedInformation {
       private String methodName;
       private Object[] args;
       private Object returnValue;

        public String getMethodName() {
            return methodName;
        }

        public void setMethodName(String methodName) {
            this.methodName = methodName;
        }

        public Object[] getArgs() {
            return args;
        }

        public void setArgs(Object[] args) {
            this.args = args;
        }

        public Object getReturnValue() {
            return returnType;
        }

        public void setReturnValue(Object returnValue) {
            this.returnValue = returnValue;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return super.hashCode();  //change your implementation as you like!
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return super.equals(obj);    //change your implementation as you like!
        }
    }
```

Now Here comes the main part, The `RecordReplyManager`. This `RecordReplyManager` gives you ***proxy object of your API*** , depending on your need of recording or replaying.

```
    public class RecordReplyManager implements java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler {

        private Object objOfApi;
        private boolean isForRecording;

        public static Object newInstance(Object obj, boolean isForRecording) {

            return java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                    obj.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                    obj.getClass().getInterfaces(),
                    new RecordReplyManager(obj, isForRecording));
        }

        private RecordReplyManager(Object obj, boolean isForRecording) {
            this.objOfApi = obj;
            this.isForRecording = isForRecording;
        }


        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            Object result;
            if (isForRecording) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("recording...");
                    System.out.println("method name: " + method.getName());
                    System.out.print("method arguments:");
                    for (Object arg : args) {
                        System.out.print(" " + arg);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    result = method.invoke(objOfApi, args);
                    System.out.println("result: " + result);
                    RecordedInformation recordedInformation = new RecordedInformation();
                    recordedInformation.setMethodName(method.getName());
                    recordedInformation.setArgs(args);
                    recordedInformation.setReturnValue(result);
                    //persist your information

                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    throw e.getTargetException();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("unexpected invocation exception: " +
                            e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    // do nothing
                }
                return result;
            } else {
                try {
                    System.out.println("replying...");
                    System.out.println("method name: " + method.getName());
                    System.out.print("method arguments:");
                    for (Object arg : args) {
                        System.out.print(" " + arg);
                    }

                    RecordedInformation recordedInformation = new RecordedInformation();
                    recordedInformation.setMethodName(method.getName());
                    recordedInformation.setArgs(args);

                    //if your invocation information (this RecordedInformation) is found in the previously collected map, then return the returnValue from that RecordedInformation.
                    //if corresponding RecordedInformation does not exists then invoke the real method (like in recording step) and wrap the collected information into RecordedInformation and persist it as you like!

                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    throw e.getTargetException();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("unexpected invocation exception: " +
                            e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    // do nothing
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to record the method invocation, all you need is getting an API proxy like bellow:

```
    MyApi realApi = new RealApi(); // using new or whatever way get your service implementation (API implementation)
    MyApi myApiWithRecorder = (MyApi) RecordReplyManager.newInstance(realApi, true); // true for recording
    myApiWithRecorder.getMySpouse("richard"); // to record getMySpouse
    myApiWithRecorder.getMyAge("parker"); // to record getMyAge
    ...
```

And to replay all you need:

```
    MyApi realApi = new RealApi(); // using new or whatever way get your service implementation (API implementation)
    MyApi myApiWithReplayer = (MyApi) RecordReplyManager.newInstance(realApi, false); // false for replaying
    myApiWithReplayer.getMySpouse("richard"); // to replay getMySpouse
    myApiWithRecorder.getMyAge("parker"); // to replay getMyAge
    ...
```

And You are Done!

***Edit:***
The basic steps of recorder and replayers can be done in above mentioned way. Now its upto you, that how you want to use or perform those steps. You can do what ever you want and whatever you like in the recorder and replayer code blocks and just choose your implementation!

Comment: If all test classes have representative interfaces, this will work, but the object returned will not be castable to (in your example above, for instance) to `RealApi`. It will also not be castable to any interface that is inherited rather than directly declared to be implemented on the class in question.

Comment: First of all, I want to clear you that, [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) is nothing but an interface to access or process data! And to that you are given an instance of its implementing class. So I think the solution will work very much to serve the requirement specified above!

Comment: And my `RecordReplyManager` returns proxy implementation of an API (not related to the methods it exposes), so this implementation will work for all the methods of that API. And just pass the API you wanna play with!

Comment: Your Replayer hits the real API whereas OP has clearly mentioned `just returning the corresponding response from the recording session - and this is the important part - without needing to talk to the above mentioned backend system` i.e. he needs an offline solution.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal - I edited my answer as you pointed the defect of the answer. My main concern was the basic structure of the recorder and replayer, and in that structure, one can decorate with his own code. Any way, thanks for your feed back and hope you will reconsider to look one more time, Cheers!

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - I am expecting, your feedback to make my answer more appropriate to serve your need. Thanks. :)

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman You've just removed `result = method.invoke(objOfApi, args);` which means you're simply returning `null` now *for all the calls* in replay mode!!

Comment: @RaviThapliyal, what should return I worte it in the commented part just after that, and I request you to read that, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I should prefix this by saying I share some of the concerns in Yves Martin's answer: that such a system may prove frustrating to work with and ultimately less helpful than it would seem at first blush.

That said, from a technical standpoint, this is an interesting problem, and I couldn't *not* take a go at it. I put together [a gist](https://gist.github.com/dfreeman/5563829) to log method calls in a fairly general way. The `CallLoggingProxy` class defined there allows usage such as the following.

```
Calendar original = CallLoggingProxy.create(Calendar.class, Calendar.getInstance());
original.getTimeInMillis(); // 1368311282470

CallLoggingProxy.ReplayInfo replayInfo = CallLoggingProxy.getReplayInfo(original);

// Persist the replay info to disk, serialize to a DB, whatever floats your boat.
// Come back and load it up later...

Calendar replay = CallLoggingProxy.replay(Calendar.class, replayInfo);
replay.getTimeInMillis(); // 1368311282470
```

You could imagine wrapping your API object with `CallLoggingProxy.create` prior to passing it into your testing methods, capturing the data afterwards, and persisting it using whatever your favorite serialization system happens to be. Later, when you want to run your tests, you can load the data back up, create a new instance based on the data with `CallLoggingProxy.replay`, and passing that into your methods instead.

The `CallLoggingProxy` is written using [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/), as Java's native `Proxy` is limited to working against interfaces. This should cover the general use case, but there are a few limitations to keep in mind:

- Classes declared `final` can't be proxied by this method. (Not easily fixable; this is a system limitation)
- The gist assumes the same input to a method will always produce the same output. (More easily fixable; the `ReplayInfo` would need to keep track of sequences of calls for each input instead of single input/output pairs.)
- The gist is not even remotely threadsafe (Fairly easily fixable; just requires a little thought and effort)

Obviously the gist is simply a proof of concept, so it's also not been very thoroughly tested, but I believe the general principle is sound. It's also possible there's a more fully baked framework out there to achieve this sort of goal, but if such a thing does exist, I'm not aware of it.

If you do decide to continue with the replay approach, then hopefully this will be enough to give you a possible direction to work in.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same needs some months ago for non-regression testing when planning a heavy technical refactoring of a large application and... I have found nothing available *as a framework*.

In fact, replaying may be particularly difficult and may only work in a specific context - no (or few) application with a standard complexity can be really considered as stateless. It is a common problem when testing persistence code with a relational database. To be relevant, the complete system initial state must be restored and each replay step must impact the global state the same way. It becomes a challenge when a system state is distributed into pieces like databases, files, memory... Let's guess what happens if a timestamp taken from a system's clock is used somewhere !

So a more pratical option is to only record... and then do a clever comparison for subsequent runs.

Depending of the number of runs you plan, a human-driven session on the application may be enough, or you have to investing in an automated scenario in a robot playing with your application user interface.

First to record: you can use dynamic proxy interface or aspect programming to intercept method call and to capture state before and after invocation. It may mean: dump concerned database tables, copy some files, serialize Java objects in text format like XML.

Then compare this reference capture with a new run. This comparison should be tuned to exclude any irrelevant elements from each piece of state, like row identifiers, timestamps, file names... to only compare data where your backend's added value shines.

Finally nothing really standard, and often a few specific scripts and codes may be enough to achieve the aim: detect as much errors as possible and try to prevent non-expected side-effects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it was not exactly what I was looking for.   I need a solution that will enable running my application in an offline situation regarding the physical hardware that the troublesome library wants to talk to.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your usecase. By the way, my remark about system state like timestamps that may be present in backend's requests and responses is still a valid point. There is a high chance that replaying complex responses without any specific tuning will fail...

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with **AOP**, aspect oriented programming. It allows to intercept method calls by byte code manipulation. Do a bit of search for examples.

In one case this can do recording, in the other replaying.

Pointers: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), AspectJ, Spring AOP.

Unfortunately one moves a bit outside the java syntax, and a simple example can better be sought elsewhere. With explanation.

*Maybe combined with unit tests / some mocking test framework for offline testing with recorded data.*

Comment: That was I was thinking too. With AOP he could achieve that when he runs the test to be recorded would automatically record each call. Then the replay could be done using Reflection while going through the recorded data. Both of them are kind of advanced stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I have already a class through which all API calls are passed which I can insert code as needed (which is why I mentioned that byte code manipulation was not necessary), so I am more looking for a framework which can help provide the actual code I need to insert.  Any suggestions for what I am actually needing?  "Do a bit of search" is a bit vague.

Answer (score 2):

you could look into ['Mockito'](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)

Example:

> ```
> //You can mock concrete classes, not only interfaces
> LinkedList mockedList = mock(LinkedList.class);
>
> //stubbing
> when(mockedList.get(0)).thenReturn("first");
> when(mockedList.get(1)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
>
> //following prints "first"
> System.out.println(mockedList.get(0));
>
> //following throws runtime exception
> System.out.println(mockedList.get(1));
>
> //following prints "null" because get(999) was not stubbed
> System.out.println(mockedList.get(999));
> ```

after you could replay each test more times and it will return data that you put in.

Comment: For your kind information, `Mockito` is a mocking framework! and A mocking object will act as what you say to do! with a mocking object you can not really capture the real behavior of an API (what API's method would return!)

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman With _only_ a mocking framework the question is indeed not answered. But as a brick for building the desired system it might be usefull, because the "replay" phase is what you get for free when you use an existing mocking framework. What's missing is just a different kind of recording phase.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman it's not correct, you could make smart stubs which will save all object state. it's very useful for testing and i think it's interesting solution for OP's task.

Comment: @A.H. I am agreed with you. and just wanted to say, what you actually said.. :P

Comment: Congrats! I'm glad that @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen picked this answer for the bounty. Top-scoring posts here focused on proxies in spite of OP repeating that interception was never a problem. Your answer rightly focussed on the playback part the only piece that OP was really missing in my opinion. +1!

Answer (score 1):

```
// pseudocode
class LogMethod {
   List<String> parameters;
   String method;
   addCallTo(String method, List<String> params):
       this.method = method;
       parameters = params;
   }
}
```

Have a list of `LogMethods` and call `new LogMethod().addCallTo()` before every call in your test method.

Comment: Thank you.  And the play back part?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of playing back the API calls sounds like a use case for the event sourcing pattern. Martin Fowler has a good article on it [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html). This is a nice pattern that records events as a sequence of objects which are then stored, you can then replay the sequence of events as required.

There is an implementation of this pattern using Akka called [Eventsourced](https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced), which may help you build the type of system you require.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some years ago. None of the above solutions would have worked for methods that are not pure functions (side effect free). The major task is in my opinion:

- how to extract a snapshot of the recorded object(s) (not only restricted to objects implementing `Serializable`)
- how to generate test code of a serialized representation in a readable way (not only restricted to beans, primitives and collections)

So I had to go my own way - with [testrecorder](http://testrecorder.amygdalum.net/).

For example, given:

```
ResultObject b = callBackend(a);

...

ResultObject callBackend(SourceObject source) {
  ...
}
```

you will only have to annotate the method like this:

```
@Recorded
ResultObject callBackend(SourceObject source) {
  ...
}
```

and start your application (the one that should be recorded) with the testrecorder agent. Testrecorder will manage all tasks for you, such as:

- serializing arguments, results, state of this, exceptions (complete object graph!)
- finding a readable representation for object construction and object matching
- generating a test from the serialized data
- you can extend recordings to global variables, input and output with annotations

An example for the test will look like this:

```
void testCallBackend() {
  //arrange
  SourceObject sourceObject1 = new SourceObject();
  sourceObject1.setState(...); // testrecorder can use setters but is not limited to them
  ... // setting up backend
  ... // setting up globals, mocking inputs

  //act
  ResultObject resultObject1 = backend.callBackend(sourceObject1);

  //assert
  assertThat(resultObject, new GenericMatcher() {
    ... // property matchers
  }.matching(ResultObject.class));
  ... // assertions on backend and sourceObject1 for potential side effects
  ... // assertions on outputs and globals
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If I understood you question correctly, you should try db4o.

You will store the objects with db4o and restore later to mock and JUnit tests.

Comment: Thank you.  It appears db4o is an object database. Do you have sample code demonstrating how I can do what I ask for?